# Processing empty files with MQSeries Adapter BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq, biztalk-2010

In receive locations using BizTalk FILE Adapter, it silently discards the received file if it is empty (0 bytes), where only a Warning entry will appear on the event log. Is it the same process if the file is received from a queue using a MQSeries Adapter?

Comment: There are other adapters than don't discard empty files, like the FTP adapter. So far as I'm aware the FILE adapter is the only one that discards empty files. But the only way to be certain if the MQSeries behaviour, is to try it out

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I'm studying an existing system that's using MQSeries adapter from the Client's end, so I have no way to see what happens to a 0byte file unless the client drops one from their end.